# How to grep for text in a file and display the paragraph that has the text?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, perl

Below is the text in the file:

```
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault

Pseudo name=Prance
Code=43B
state=good
```

I need to grep for "42B" and get the output from the above text like:

```
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault
```

Does anyone have idea on how to achieve this using `grep`/`awk`/`sed`?

Comment: You tagged this question with just "grep". Are you only looking for "grep" solutions then? In the question you specify  awk & sed too. Can we add those tags? I wasn't sure of your intent when I edited the question last night.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024410/how-to-get-the-paragraph-contain-the-key-words-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 50):

With `awk`

```
awk -v RS='' '/42B/' file
```

`RS=` changes the input record separator from a newline to blank lines. If any field in an record contains `/42B/` print the record.

`''` (the null string) is a magic value used to represent blank lines [according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

> If **RS** is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a `<newline>` plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a `<newline>` shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of **FS** is.

The output paragraphs will not be separated since the output separator remains a single newline. To ensure that there is a blank line between output paragraphs, set the output record separator to two newlines:

```
awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/42B/' file
```

Comment: fingers were on autopilot.

Comment: @jasonwryan, unless you need access to the file name within awk (`FILENAME`), it's not a bad idea to use redirection as that avoids problems for filename containing `=` or starting with `-` (or being `-`), makes for consistent error messages, and avoids running `awk` or performing other redirections if the input file can't be opened.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming the data is structured so that it's always the line before and after that you want you can make use of grep's `-A` (after) and `-B` (before) switches to tell it to include the 1 line before the match and 1 line after it:

```
$ grep -A 1 -B 1 "42B" sample.txt
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault
```

If you want the same number lines before and after the search term you can use the `-C` (context) switch:

```
$ grep -C 1 "42B" sample.txt
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault
```

If you'd like to be more stringent when matching the multiple lines you can use the tool [`pcregrep`](http://linuxcommand.gds.tuwien.ac.at/man_pages/pcregrep1.html), to match a pattern over multiple lines:

```
$ pcregrep -M 'Pseudo.*\n.*42B.*\nstate.*' sample.txt
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault
```

The above pattern matches as follows:

- `-M` - multiple lines
- `'Pseudo.*\n.*42B.*\nstate.*'` - matches a group of strings where the first string starts with the word `"Pseudo"` followed by any characters up until a end of line `\n`, followed by any characters up until the string `"42B"` followed by any characters up until another end of line (`\n`), followed by the string `"state"`followed by any characters.

Answer (score 6):

The `grep` of some flavours of Unix have the `-p` flag for "paragraph". I know [AIX does](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=g-grep-command#grep__row-d3e144100).

```
grep -p 42B <myfile>
```

would do exactly what you're asking for there. YMMV and GNU grep doesn't have this flag.

Comment: Having the -p flag would be wonderful.  Especially if used together with -v so you could exclude entire paragraphs from output.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a similarly easy way to do it with awk, but in perl:

```
cat file | perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/="\n\n" }; print if $_ =~ /42B/;'
```

That basically says to split the file into chunks delimited by blank lines, then to only print those chunks that match your regular expression.

Comment: This can be simplified by using options and shorthands, and losing the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html); `perl -00 -ne 'print if /42B/' file`

Answer (score 3):

An other perl solution, without a trailing empty line:

```
perl -00ne 'if ($_ =~ /42B/) {chomp($_); printf "%s\n",$_}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
% perl -00ne 'if ($_ =~ /42B/) {chomp($_); printf "%s\n",$_}' foo
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault

% cat foo
Pseudo name=Apple
Code=42B
state=fault

Pseudo name=Prance
Code=43B
state=good
```

Comment: Or shorter (and thus more readable), as triplee wrote in a comment: 
 `perl -00 -ne 'print if /42B/' file`.