# grep with piping and showing multiple lines

Tags: grep, pipe, string

I am trying to use `grep` to search a large text file, and return the paragraph containing a few key words. I also want to return the surrounding lines in the result. So, for example I have the following words I am going to search for: blue, green, yellow. If I wanted to find the paragraph containing all 3 words, in the file called 'colors.txt', I tried the following code:

`grep blue colors.txt | grep green | grep yellow`

This only gave me the listings for yellow though, and not the ones that had yellow, green and blue, in the paragraph.

I then wanted to display the surrounding words, so used something like

`grep -B 5 blue colors.txt | grep green colors.txt` etc etc

In summary - I have a large text file, and I want to find the section containing the three colours, but display the lines surrounding it.

Comment: You need to decide what you want. Do you want to "return the paragraph"? Or, do you want to return the five preceding lines (as per -B5)? Or, what?

Comment: See [How to grep for text in a file and display the paragraph that has the text?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82944) Most of the solutions there could be easily adapted to your needs.

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36960668/3776858

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00 -n -e 'print if (m/blue/i && m/green/i && m/yellow/i)' filename
```

This uses `perl`'s paragraph-reading mode (`-00`) to print only paragraphs containing all three words (with case-insensitive matches).

a 'paragraph' is one or more lines of text, separated from other paragraphs by at least one blank line.

e.g. I saved the text of your question into a file, and ran this `perl` one-liner on it.  Output is:

```
i am trying to use grep to search a large text file, and return the
paragraph containing a few key words. I also want to return the
surrounding lines in the result. So, for example I have the following
words I am going to search for: blue, green, yellow. If I wanted to find
the paragraph containing all 3 words, in the file called 'colors.txt', I
tried the following code:

grep blue colors.txt | grep green | grep yellow

This only gave me the listings for yellow though, and not the ones that
had yellow, green and blue, in the paragraph.
```

i.e. only 3 paragraphs of output, whereas your question had 7 paragraphs.