# How to grep/awk/sed for text in a log and display the chunk that has the text?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I'm looking for something pretty similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82944/how-to-grep-for-text-in-a-file-and-display-the-paragraph-that-has-the-text).

The logs look like this:

```
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A ONE LINE ERROR
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - Another ERROR 
[09:44:22] [main] SOMETHING DIFFERENT
[09:44:22] [main] SOMETHING DIFFERENT AGAIN
[09:44:22] [main] WARN [url/location] - ANOTHER ONE LINE WARN
```

Line after line with no empty lines between them, though occasionally there are indents when further info is available for a specific piece.

I want to be able to pull every line that includes `ERROR` (ideally as a script that can pull `ERROR` And/Or `FAIL`, `WARN`, etc.) and display them according to a parameter. It'll make sifting through logs for fails and whatnot much easier.

Comment: You'll need to define what a "chunk" is - beyond the fact that it *isn't* delimited by blank lines

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make it so that what's shown in the block above is line after line instead of line, space, line. Each message has its own line with a timestamp at the beginning, if it's possible to sort by that.

Comment: You should be able to preserve text formating by using code markdown (basically select it then press Ctrl-K) - see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) in the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I've got something working with [awk -v FS='' '/ERROR/' file.txt] that seems to work, though only in my test file where I copied a few lines from the log into a new file. Is there a size limit where the command stops working? Minus the brackets, as I'm new to SE and don't know much of the forum syntax.

Comment: I'm not aware of any size limit. However I still don't understand what your input and desired output are.

Comment: I don't know how to make it more clear than I have already. I want to have every line in a log (starting with a timestamp and ending at the next timestamp) that has ERROR in it to be printed.

Comment: @Patremagne I don't see why the `awk` command you quoted wouldn't work if all you want is the matching lines. Setting `FS` is unnecessary, but shouldn't matter. Just printing lines containing a pattern is simple with any of the tools you mention, and perhaps the simplicity of it is what causes confusion. (And the word "chunk" and mentioning indentations). `awk '/ERROR/' in.txt`, `grep ERROR in.txt` and `sed -n '/ERROR/p' in.txt` should all print the lines containing "ERROR" anywhere on the line, though grep is made just for this.

Answer (score 2):

`GNU grep` is able to do this quite simply.  From `man grep`:

> Two regular expressions may be joined by the infix operator |; the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either subexpression.

```
grep "ERROR\|FAIL\|WARN" /path/to/example.log
```

`egrep` eliminates the need for escaping the `|` symbols.

```
egrep "ERROR|FAIL|WARN" /path/to/example.log
```

Comment: Why is `|` called "infix operator", when it means "OR" here? Also, your answer will not output following lines, if they start with whitespace.

Comment: That is a good question for which I do not know the answer.  I believe the pertinent information is contained in the second half of that sentence: `the resulting regular expression matches any string matching either subexpression`.  As for a `leading whitespace`, it works on any line containing `ERROR, FAIL, or WARN` on my system.  I have edited the answer to include `GNU`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking that up. I often use the word "infix", in the context "Reverse incremental infix search" (CTRL-R), but i had never seen it written in the context you quoted. 2) I meant lines, that start with whitespace, but follow a line containing the keyword, while not themselves containing the keyword.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1. (I had misunderstood OP's desired input format.)

Comment: @AlexStragies I've sort of found the issue that has me saying some things aren't working. The actual log file that I want to pull errors from won't work with any of the commands in this thread, but the same exact text (copied/pasted word for word from the original) pasted into a fresh text file works. I have both read/write permissions, so I'm not sure why the original log or even duplicates of it won't obey.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your log file looks like this?

example.log:

```
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A ONE LINE ERROR
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR 
    with whitepace indention
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR 
       with tab indention
[09:44:22] [main] SOMETHING DIFFERENT
[09:44:22] [main] SOMETHING DIFFERENT
       with tab indention
[09:44:22] [main] WARN [url/location] - ANOTHER ONE LINE WARN
```

Admittedly not a one-liner and in perl, but it should do the job:

logsifter.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $buffer="";

while(my $line= <>){
  chomp $line;
  if($line=~/ERROR|INFO|WARN/){
    print "$buffer\n" if $buffer;
    $buffer = $line;
  }
  elsif($line=~/^\s+(.*)$/){
    $buffer .= $1 if $buffer;
  }
  else{
    if($buffer){
      print "$buffer\n";
      $buffer ="";
    }
  }
}

print "$buffer\n";
```

call it like:

```
perl logsifter.pl < example.log
 [09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A ONE LINE ERROR
 [09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR with whitepace indention
 [09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR with tab indention
 [09:44:22] [main] WARN [url/location] - ANOTHER ONE LINE WARN
```

Comment: I tried this and the output was just every line in the text file, regardless of whether or not it included ERROR. It's entirely likely I did something wrong, as I mentioned I'm new to all this.

Comment: @Patremagne : Murphy and I, we both basically use the same algorithm. I haven't run his version, but on first glance it looks correct .  You may have missed, that his version filters for ERROR|INFO|WARN, and trailing lines

Comment: @AlexStragies the only small difference is, that I remove the line breaks in case of an  indent. this way everything is in one line and easier to process with grep if necessary

Comment: @AlexStragies Ahh I missed that INFO was in the perl script, so I removed it and it worked on my test text file that only includes 10 or so lines from the actual log. Unfortunately when I try it on the log itself, there's no output.

Comment: @Patremagne I tested my solution with my provided example.log. It puts out the data as shown above.

Comment: @murphy Yes, it works for me as well with my test log of 10 lines, but the log I actually want to probe through has 2500 lines and has no output when I run it through your solution.

Comment: @Patremagne if you upload your file here https://gist.github.com/ and post the url, I will look into it.

Comment: @murphy I'd rather not post it publicly, but I can send it to you on some other platform.

Answer (score 1):

Now, that your Data format has been established, the answer becomes a lot simpler: `grep` was built for *this*.

Use as `grep '<PATTERN>' <dataFile>`

Where `<PATTERN>` is `SearchWORD1` or `SearchW1\|SearchW2`

The answer below was written, when me and @murphy still had wrong assumptions about the dataformat:

Here is a one-line awk program that only searches for *ERROR*:

`awk '/ERROR/{a=1;print} /^ / || /^\t/ {if (a) print;next} !/ERROR/ {a=0}'`

You could make this into a flexible shell-function with parameter:

```
searchlog(){ awk -f <( echo "
/$1/{a=1;print}
/^ /||/^\t/{if (a) print;next}
! /$1/{a=0}
"); }
```

Run it either as `LogData_generated_by_program | searchlog <PATTERN>`, or `searchlog <PATTERN> < File_containing_Log_Data`.

For the example data format the other answerer "guessed", this results in:

```
$ searchlog ERROR < /tmp/exampleData
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A ONE LINE ERROR
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR 
    with whitepace indention
[09:44:22] [main] ERROR [url/location] - A MULTI LINE ERROR 
       with tab indention
```

Comment: Sorry for my Linux ignorance, but what do you mean by "push your data into STDIN" ?