# Grep a paragraph that matches words from a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file (`myfile`) organized in paragraphs, i.e. with empty lines separating the entries. I want to retrieve some of these paragraphs according to `match`.

Now, it's all fun and games when the match is only one: I simply do `awk -v RS='' '/match/ {print}' myfile`, as in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82944/how-to-grep-for-text-in-a-file-and-display-the-paragraph-that-has-the-text). The thing is that I have hundreds of matches to find in `file`, which I collected in another file (`matchfile`). If I had to retrieve only the matching line, I'd do a `grep -f matchfile myfile`.

Is there a way to do something similar to `grep -f` retrieving the whole paragraph? My Unix flavour doesn't support `grep -p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn paragraphs into single lines, use `grep -f matchfile` on the result and then restore the newlines:

```
sed '/^$/s/^/\x02/' myfile | tr \\n$'\002' $'\003'\\n \
| grep -f matchfile |  tr $'\003' \\n | head -n -1
```

You can do without the `head` if the trailing empty line in the output doesn't bother you.
So... `sed` adds `\x02` to the beginning of each empty line then `tr` translates all newlines to `\x03` and all `\x02` to newlines (effectively turning all paragraphs into single lines where the original lines are fields separated by some low ascii char that's unlikely to occur in your text file - in this case `\x03`) then `grep` selects only the matching *"lines"*; finally, the second `tr` restores the newlines and `head` discards the trailing empty line (you could use any other tool e.g. `sed \$d`).
Really, the easiest way to understand how this works is to run it in steps: run only the 1st command, then the 1st & 2nd and so on... and observe the output - it should be self-explanatory<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1: if you got familiar with `tr` after reading the manual...</sup>

Comment: I'm not a `perl` guy but I'm sure `perl` is more suited for this job...

Comment: I like your solution, it's the style I normally use to solve problems. Could you explain what you did here? I'm not quite familiar with `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

Come on, don't give up on `awk` so fast !

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
          aMatch[NR]=$0
          n=FNR
          next;
    }
    {
          RS="\n( |\t)*\n"
          for(i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
             if($0 ~ aMatch[i]) {
               print
               printf "\n"
               break                   
             }                 
          }
    }' matchFile myFile | head -n-1
```

You might want to put that into a script though :

```
awk -f myscript.awk matchFile myFile | head -n-1
```

The solution in `awk` script form, with annotations on what it does:

```
# This block's instructions will only be executed for the first file (containing the lines to be matched)
# NR = number of line read, and FNR = number of line read in current file   
# So the predicate NR == FNR is only true when reading the first file !
NR == FNR {
   aMatch[NR]=$0          # Store the line to match in an array
   n=FNR                  # Store the number of matches
   next;                  # Tells awk to skip further instructions (they are intended for the other file) and process the next record
}
# We are now processing the second file (containing the paragraphs)
{
   RS="\n( |\t)*\n"          # Set record separator to a blank line. Instead of a single line, a record is now the entire paragraph
   for(i=1; i<n+1; i++) {    # Loop on all possible matches
      if($0 ~ aMatch[i]) {   # If $0 (the whole record i.e. paragraph) matches a line we read in file 1 then
         print               # Print the record (i.e. current paragraph)
         printf "\n"         # Print a new line to separate them. However we will end up with a trailing newline, hence the pipe to head -n-1 to get rid of it.
         break               # We need to break out of the loop otherwise paragraphs with n matches will be printed n times
      }                      # End of loop on matches
   }                         # End of 2nd file processing
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job! Can you explain in detail what did you do here, so next time I won't give up on poor `awk`?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll edit the post and add comments !

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to do this:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" '/match/' myfile
```