# awk paragraph does not work

Tags: awk, sed, grep, perl

I have downloaded the KingBase Lite 2018 Update 3 file from [here](http://www.kingbase-chess.net/). I now want to extract data from a single event such as the "FIDE Candidates 2018": I want to get all the paragraphs containing this text and the paragraph below it, so I have the whole pgn for each game.

To first just get the paragraph that contains the text, I followed [these recommendations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82944/how-to-grep-for-text-in-a-file-and-display-the-paragraph-that-has-the-text).

However, when I try `awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/FIDE Candidates 2018/' KingBaseLite2018-03.pgn`, it just prints the whole file. When I search for a word that does not exist, it does not print anything. So I assume it does the search correctly, but it somehow does not properly cut at new lines. There might be something awkward about the new line characters in that file. When I try other suggestions from the above link like using perl, I get the same result.

What can I do to get the paragraph now? And how can I include one paragraph below as well?

Comment: Might be due to your use of `RS`? Anyhow, you should post a sample input and desired output to help those who want to help you reproduce your issue and test the solutions.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the file has Windows-style CRLF line-endings

Comment: ... although it's not entirely equivalent, probably setting `RS='\r\n\r\n'` is sufficient in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and unzipped the file, and the line endings are CRLF, so you need to account for that, either by using a tool like [`fromdos`](https://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/index.shtml), or if you don't want to modify the file, you can to tell Perl that you want it to do the translation with its `:crlf` [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) layer, which is what I'm doing below with the `PERLIO` environment variable. (There are other ways to change the layers, but this one was easiest for a one-liner.)

I'm using the [flip-flop operator `...`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to extract only the paragraph that matches the regex plus the following one that matches `/^1\./` (since all the paragraphs in the file start with either `[` or `1.`).

```bash
wget http://kingbase-chess.net/download/650 -O KingBaseLite2018-03.zip
unzip KingBaseLite2018-03.zip
PERLIO=:crlf perl -00ne 'print if /"FIDE Candidates 2018"/.../^1\./' KingBaseLite2018-03.pgn
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much :)