# How to grep lines for a specific profile starting with [default]

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, aws

I'm trying to parse the lines of an `.aws/config` or `.aws/credentials` file of a specific profile such as `[default]` or `[prod]`.

File example

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[nonprod]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[uat]
region = us-east-2
output = json

[prod]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

Does anybody have a (aws, sed, grep, etc) script that searches for (and displays) the lines after e.g. `[default]` until the start of the next profile, or if searching for prod starting with `[prod]` until the end of the file?

Examples

```
searchawsconfig default
searchawsconfig prod
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep for text in a file and display the paragraph that has the text?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82944/how-to-grep-for-text-in-a-file-and-display-the-paragraph-that-has-the-text)

Comment: The paragraph approach is pretty neat, but I was wondering if there are any other solutions than blank separated paragraphs? e.g. maybe search for the profile name, start outputting the next line util there is a [ at the beginning of the line?

Comment: What's a "profile" - is it a name in square brackets?

Comment: @roaima yes, aws calls those profiles

Answer (score 3):

If the profiles are blank-separated, then you can use awk in *paragraph mode* ex.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v p='[uat]' '$1 == p' yourfile
[uat]
region = us-east-2
output = json
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl in "paragraph mode":

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if /\[default\]/' file 
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

or

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print if /\[prod\]/' file 
[prod]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

You could make this into a shell function by adding these lines to your shell's initialization file (e.g `~/.bashrc`):

```bsh
searchawsconfig(){
    perl -00 -ne 'print if /\['"$1"'\]/' "$2" 
}
```

You can then do:

```
$ searchawsconfig prod file 
[prod]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

Answer (score 1):

abstract:

```
awk '$1==p' RS= p='[default]' ./tst
```

---

Using the paragraph mode to split the input file into records that are delimited with an "empty line" (two consecutive `\n`).

You can do regex matching with (escape `[]` as they are special in regex) (use `^` to mark the start of a line):

```
awk -vRS='' '/^\[default\]/' ./tst
```

Or you can do text matching (full **first** line) with:

```
awk -vRS='' '$1 == "[default]"' ./tst
```

Or (more flexible) use variables set in the command line:

```
awk '$1==p' RS= p='[default]' ./tst
```

Make sure to use some form of a path, like the relative path `./` to ensure that the file name is parsed as a filename even if it contains `=`.

Or, using environment variables:

```
RS='' SECTION='default'   \
    awk   'BEGIN{RS=ENVIRON["RS"]} $1=="[" ENVIRON["SECTION"] "]" ' \
        ./tst
```